# ipad left alignment

Tags: ipad, alignment

It seems on most of my sites they display almost correctly on an ipad or iphone with the exception of them looking like they are left aligned - although it is really more than that.

It seems as if each device has a small right side margin type of area which is somehow associated with the body (when I change the body background color this color changes).

On this particular site there is a repeating background image which then gets cutoff/doesn't keep repeating.  Obviously I'm missing some type of coding - I've googled and tried several different solutions but none have worked.

918nawreck.com

Comment: Are you talking about this ?
#main-container {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url(http://918nawreck.com/wp-content/themes/dandelion/images/bg.png);
background-repeat:repeat no-repeat;}

Comment: Yes, that is the image I am referring to in this particular case.  But it is not limited to a site with a background image.  All sites seem to be left aligned.  Here is another example:  airdoctortulsa.com.  So I'm specifically looking for an answer on how to solve this issue with all sites or why this is happening.

Comment: add this body {
  background-color:#B0B0B0 !important;
}
on  airdoctortulsa.com

Comment: if u want to repeat that background image go to css file and change
#main-container { background-repeat:no-repeat;} to #main-container { background-repeat:repeat;}

Comment: I think you are missing my question.  I know how to style the background I'm not having an issue with that.  I'm having an issue that on the Ipad everything seems to be left aligned.  I want to know how to get the websites centered on the ipad correctly as they are in a normal browser.